# How can I create an alias for a function name?

Tags: functions, defun, aliases, defalias

Does Elisp allow the equivalent of an alias for a function name?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can have any number of aliases for the same function.

To do that, use `defalias` (or `fset`, but `defalias` is generally recommended).

Example: define `mop` as an alias for `means-of-production`.

```lisp
(defalias 'mop 'means-of-production)
```

`C-h f defalias` says:

> `defalias` is a built-in function in `C source code`.
>
> (defalias SYMBOL DEFINITION &optional DOCSTRING)
>
> Set `SYMBOL`'s function definition to `DEFINITION`.
>
> Associates the function with the current load file, if any.
>
> The optional third argument `DOCSTRING` specifies the documentation string
> for `SYMBOL`; if it is omitted or `nil`, `SYMBOL` uses the documentation string
> determined by `DEFINITION`.
>
> Internally, this normally uses `fset`, but if `SYMBOL` has a
> `defalias-fset-function` property, the associated value is used instead.
>
> The return value is undefined.

See also the Elisp manual, node [Defining Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Functions.html).